# makefile for a yacc and flex

Tags: c, makefile, flex-lexer, yacc

I have a `make`-based project involving `yacc` and `lex`, but `make` is performing actions that I do not expect and cannot explain from my makefile:

```
a.out: lex.yy.o y.tab.o ass3_14CS101.o
    gcc lex.yy.o y.tab.o ass3_14CS101.o -lfl
ass3_14CS101.o: ass3_14CS101.c
    gcc -c ass3_14CS101.c
lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c
    gcc -c lex.yy.c
y.tab.o: y.tab.c
    gcc -c y.tab.c
lex.yy.c: ass3_14CS101.l y.tab.h
    flex ass3_14CS101.l
y.tab.c: ass3_14CS101.y
    yacc -dtv ass3_14CS101.y -W
y.tab.h: ass3_14CS101.y
    yacc -dtv ass3_14CS101.y -W
clean:
    rm lex.yy.c y.tab.c y.tab.h lex.yy.o y.tab.o ass3_14CS101.o y.output a.out
test: 
    ./a.out < ass3_14CS101_test.c
```

Here is the output of one `make` run:

> yacc -dtv ass3_14CS10061.y -W
>   ass3_14CS10061.y:48.10: warning: empty rule without %empty [-Wempty-rule]
>   statement : ;
>         ^
>   flex ass3_14CS10061.l
>   ass3_14CS10061.l:77: warning, rule cannot be matched
>   gcc -c lex.yy.c
>   gcc -c y.tab.c
>   yacc  ass3_14CS10061.y
>   **mv -f y.tab.c ass3_14CS10061.c**
>   gcc -c ass3_14CS10061.c
>   gcc lex.yy.o y.tab.o ass3_14CS10061.o -lfl
>   ass3_14CS10061.o: In function `yyparse':
>   ass3_14CS10061.c:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of `yyparse'
>   y.tab.o:y.tab.c:(.text+0x289): first defined here
>   ass3_14CS10061.o: In function `yyerror':
>   ass3_14CS10061.c:(.text+0x7f6): multiple definition of `yyerror'
>   y.tab.o:y.tab.c:(.text+0xd61): first defined here
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [a.out] Error 1

Where did the `mv -f` command  (the **bold** line above) come from?  There is no such command in the Makefile, and it is causing the build to fail.

Comment: 1.  find the minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem - isolate the problem yourself (doing that will frequently lead you to the solution) 2. then post the minimal example here with proper formatting.

Comment: Hi Sayan - I've applied some markup to your code and output so it's clearer to read now; but your question does still need some work. If you could do some investigation yourself first to pin down the problem (that's what Mark Galeck means when he says to find a minimal example), that would help people help you with answering the question.

Comment: That doesn't look like a makefile. Format that mess properly, maybe it then look more like what you mean. And if that is about your makefile, why add the other tags?

Comment: I'm inclined to think that the makefile you present is not the one being used.  If you're using GNU `make`, it will look for `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, and `Makefile`, in that order, and use the first it finds.  Note in particular that although the last of those is the traditional name, the other two alternatives both override it.  If you are looking in the wrong file then that could well explain your confusion.

Answer (score 4):

You have:

```
a.out: lex.yy.o y.tab.o ass3_14CS101.o
    gcc lex.yy.o y.tab.o ass3_14CS101.o -lfl
ass3_14CS101.o: ass3_14CS101.c
    gcc -c ass3_14CS101.c
```

The first rule says the compilation needs to ensure `ass3_14CS101.o` is up to date.  The second rule says you create `ass3_14CS101.o` by compiling `ass3_14CS101.c`.  None of the other specified rules say anything about how to create `ass3_14CS101.c`, but `make` is clever.

Given that there's a file `ass3_14CS101.y`, `make` knows how to create `ass3_14CS101.c` from it: it runs `yacc` and moves `yy.tab.c` to `ass3_14CS101.c`.  So, that's what you see it doing.

You might note that `make` is running the `yacc` command again before the `mv` you noted; and that invocation is different from the first.

You need to use more macros.  `YACC` contains the name of the Yacc-like program, and `YFLAGS` conventionally contains the arguments to it (it looks like you prefer `-dtv -W` as the Yacc flags).  Similarly with the C compiler (`CC` and `CFLAGS`) and linking often adds `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` — so you end up with a command line like:

```
${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${OBJECTFILES} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}
```

as the linking command line.  The macro I designated as `${OBJECTFILES}` is a list of the object files that should be linked.  Note that `${CFLAGS}` is included; it often contains the `-g` option for debug information, and you need that in the link command line as well as the object file command lines.

One major benefit of using macros is that you can adjust the compilation from the `make` command line if need so be — without editing the `makefile`.

Comment: There is a file name ass_14CS101.c already present in the same directory. Then why does 'make'  create another .c file from the .y file ?

Comment: I think it is because `make` is set up, via the list of suffixes in the `.SUFFIXES` rule, to prefer building from the `.y` file to an existing `.c` file.